# Java - Select the line to read data in JXL

Tags: java, jxl

My spreadsheet has a label and I would like to read it from line 2.

But I'm not getting a simple way to do this in JXL, I've read the documentation and can not implement it.

I tried `String login = sheet.getCell(0, 2, i).getContents();` but it did not work.

It only reads normally if it only has 2 parameters, specifying the i of the for and column, as: `String login = sheet.getCell(0, i).getContents();`

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new java.io.File("tools/file.xls"));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);  
int rowCount = sheet.getRows();
    for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {   

        String login = sheet.getCell(0, i).getContents();
        String password = sheet.getCell(1, i).getContents();    
    }
workbook.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GetCell() method possibilities are:**

> getCell(int column, int row) - ex. getCell(1,4)
>
> getCell(String loc) - ex. getCell("A4")

There isn't any 3 parameters getCell() method.

If you would like to start scraping from second row, change your "i" value.

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new java.io.File("aaa.xls"));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
int rowCount = sheet.getRows();
int startingRowPosition = 2;
for(int i = startingRowPosition; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    String login = sheet.getCell(0, i).getContents();
    String password = sheet.getCell(1, i).getContents();

    System.out.println("Login: " + login + " Password: " + password);
}
workbook.close();
```

Comment: Simple and great.